# Calculating hit probability on a moving player

Tags: probability, 3d

Everything is in $3$d.

Assuming the player speed is $375$ units/second, and the missile being casted travels at $2000$ units/second with an initial cast delay of $0.25$s and width of $150$ units, the player can easily change direction (or simply stop moving) to evade the missile. I'm solving the interception point using the quadratic equation method.

The missile can be cast only once every $30$ seconds for example, so it hitting is highly preferred and the range of it is capped at eg $1200$ units.

The missile can not change directions and is a straight line.

How would I go about creating a somewhat accurate hit probability formula that generates a value between $0.0$ and $1.0$, assuming I have the interception point, last path change time, average time in which the player changes path etc?

I'm totally lost.

Comment: What is stopping the player from evading all missiles?

Comment: @cgss the fact that the player is a human and that theres other things going on in the game and the primary focus is not evading. The game is similar to Dota 2.

Comment: The problem is that we need those fact. Based only on the info in your question, the player can always evade.

Comment: Interesting, but it needs more definition, and looks very difficult. The cast delay seems to be irrelevant. I would start with a simpler geometry - eg target can only move on a circle, missile launched from the centre of the circle.

Comment: That is correct. The player *can* (if he has enought time to do so) always evade if he responds instantly, which will happen very rarely, by luck. If the distance to the target is eg $300$, the total time for the missile to hit would be $0.25$ + $2000$/$300$ = $0.45$. In order to evade he would need atleast 0.4 seconds, near impossible for example.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are asking for. If the target can predict where the missile will be and can change direction whenever it chooses, then it can adopt an evasive strategy. Depending on the position of the target relative to the missile launcher at the time the missile is launched, we can predict with certainty whether the target will escape or get hit. So it is not clear what probability you are asking for.

Comment: What I am asking for is how I would roughly predict the chance that the missile hits, based on factors such as distance to player, time to hit, width of missile, speed of player, the average time the player changes path/direction etc.  The player can not adapt as the scenario is different every cast, in one scenario the player might be trying to escape and try to juke and in the other he would be fighting and being unable to move.